# How do I change the background color of AdControl?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to change background color of AdControl in WP7?
I tried setting the background property of the control and it does not work.

Comment: I am expriencing this issue also. adControl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White); Has no affect. Did you ever work out the issue.

Comment: I just tried to edit the style of the AdControl and failed. Then I thought maybe you are not allowed to do this?